# Python: form a list based on the same values

Tags: python, list

consider `x = [10,10,20,20,20,30]` 
How do i form another `list_x1` which contains only same values example: `list_x1 = [10,10]` 
and `list_x2 =[20,20]` and `list_x3 =[30]` ?

Comment: Do the new lists need to go into separate variables? That's not convenient if you don't know in advance how many there will be. How about a list of lists: `[[10,10], [20,20], [30]]`?

Comment: Will the input list always be sorted? If not, will the identical values always be grouped together in the input list?

Comment: In your first list there's three instances of `20`, but in example results there's only two. Is this a mistake or did you forget to tell us something about the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby 
>>> x = [10,10,20,20,20,30]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(x)]
[[10, 10], [20, 20, 20], [30]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use counter.

```
from collections import Counter

x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
my_counter = Counter(x)
d = {'list_x{0}'.format(key): [key] * my_counter[key] for key in my_counter}

>>> d
{'list_x10': [10, 10], 'list_x20': [20, 20, 20], 'list_x30': [30]}
```

One of the issues with your request is that you would need to pre-assign variables, which aren't initially know.  I've used a dictionary as a container to hold them.

For a list, [10] * 3 results in [10, 10, 10].  So, `[k] * my_counter` multiplies the unique key value by the number of occurrences.

Comment: If the key `k` equals 10, 'list_x{0}'.format(10)` puts the value 10 inside the curly brackets in the text. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting

Comment: Thanks.  That was shorthand for counter.  I reassigned it with my_counter which is more readable, but missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way is @Alexander's idea with collections, but I always find it helpful to look at more 'native' python code to see what's going on. So here's a way to do it:

```
x = [10,10,20,20,20,30]

def foo(iterable):
    for val in iterable:
        cnt = iterable.count(val)
        iterable = list(filter(lambda x: x != val, iterable))
        if cnt:
            yield [val]*cnt

for _ in foo(x):
    print(_)
```

Note that the complexity factor is going to be fairly high. Certainly not O(n) because you have to:

- Iterate through each of the values in our main `for val in iterable`
- Iterate through each of the values every time we call `iterable.count`
- Iterate through each of the values when we `filter()` them to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> def list_gen(in_list, elem):
...     count = collections.Counter(in_list)
...     return [elem] * count[elem]
... 

>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]

>>> list_gen(a, 2)
[2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but this code will generate a list of lists separating the values.

```
x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
uniques = set(x)
output = []
for unique in uniques:
    unique_count = x.count(unique)
    temp = []
    for i in range(0, unique_count):
        temp.append(unique)
    output.append(temp)
```

You can then use list comprehensions on `output`